# Connect to Apache Accumulo via .NET

Tags: java, .net, nosql, ikvm, accumulo

Currently I succeed to create an Ubuntu virtual machine and install Hadoop, Zookeeper and Accumulo.
Now I need to create a test ASP.NET MVC application that reads and writes data to the Accumulo.

I've been looking around for .NET clients or some kind of rest API but my searches where unsuccessful. Any snippet I could find was in Java. 
So one of the options I am considering at the moment is to convert Java client into .NET library using IKVM.NET.

So my question are

- Is there any .NET provider for Apache Accumulo?
- If no provider, does it expose some kind of REST API to program against?
- If no REST what is the endpoint that I could use (and documentation links if possible) to create .NET provider myself?
- Is converting Java lib a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo has a couple of ways to connect through Thrift, which you should be able to use .NET.

[In 1.5, there is something called Proxy, a separate service that handles connections, that handles connections and has a thrift interface.](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/accumulo_user_manual.html#_creating_a_proxy_client)

There is some code for using Thrift against 1.4, but I don't think it is well documented. It's there somewhere, though!